# PHP - https:// POST-Request?

Tags: php, facebook, post, https, request

where's my mistake in the code?

```
<?php
    error_reporting(-1);
    function PostRequest($url, $referer, $_data) {
        // convert variables array to string:
        $data = array();
        while(list($n,$v) = each($_data)){
            $data[] = "$n=$v";
        }
        $data = implode('&', $data);
        // format --> test1=a&test2=b etc.

        // parse the given URL
        $url = parse_url($url);

        // extract host and path:
        $host = $url['host'];
        $path = $url['path'];

        // open a socket connection on port 80
        $fp = fsockopen("ssl://".$host, 443);

        // send the request headers:
        fputs($fp, "POST $path HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Host: $host\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Referer: $referer\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Content-length: ". strlen($data) ."\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
        fputs($fp, $data);

        $result = '';
        $safe=0;
        while(!feof($fp)&&$safe<1000) {
            // receive the results of the request
            $result .= fgets($fp, 128);
            $safe++;
        }

        // close the socket connection:
        fclose($fp);

        // split the result header from the content
        $result = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);

        $header = isset($result[0]) ? $result[0] : '';
        $content = isset($result[1]) ? $result[1] : '';

        // return as array:
        return array($header, $content);
    }

    /*
    ** The example:
    */

    // submit these variables to the server:
    $data = array(
        'email'=>'testemail',
        'pass'=>'testpass'
    );

    list($header, $content) = PostRequest("https://login.facebook.com/login.php", "http://facebook.com", $data);
    // print the result of the whole request:
    print $content;
?>
```

I want to make an auto login script for some sites for the private use, this code should perform a redirection to facebook and automaticly log into an account, but the code isn't working, my browser window is still blank.

Would be great if anyone, could help me. I already tried this with CURL, but my test-site Facebook says, that Cookies aren't enabled.

Comment: Use cURL. Don't socket into an HTTPS server unless you understand the private and public keys and handshakes required to successfully complete an HTTPS request.

Comment: Do you have ssl configured on your server?

Comment: I tried cURL, but it wasnt working, because of the cookies :(

Comment: Just so you know, this may well get your Facebook account blocked.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the response is a header redirect with no body.

Try it using [this class](http://download.networkm.net/code/php/class.httprequest.1.3.php.tar.gz) I wrote for situations where cURL is not available - it does exactly what you are trying to do there, but takes a lot of the work out of it by handling the connection and message construction for you, as well as header redirects. Also provides meaningful error messages. Documented in comments at the top of the file.

Use the above class and try the following code (**EDITED FOR COOKIES**):

```
<?php

  function process_cookies ($httpobj, $cookiejar = array()) {
    // Function get the cookies that should be sent in the next request
    if (!count($cookies = $httpobj->getResponseCookies())) return $cookiejar;
    foreach ($cookies as $key => $data) {
      if ($data['value'] !== '' && (!isset($data['expirestime']) || $data['expirestime'] > time())) {
        $cookiejar[$key] = $data['value'];
      } else if (isset($cookiejar[$key])) {
        unset($cookiejar[$key]);
      }
    }
    return $cookiejar;
  }

  $url1 = 'http://www.facebook.com/';
  $url2 = 'https://login.facebook.com/login.php';

  // Fetch the class
  require('class.httprequest.php');

  // Create an object and get the main page of facebook.com
  $request1 = new httprequest;
  if (!$request1->setRequestURL($url1)) exit("Error setting request 1 URL: ".$request1->getLastErrorStr()."<br>\r\n");
  if (!$request1->sendRequest()) exit("Error sending request 1: ".$request1->getLastErrorStr()."<br>\r\n");

  // Create an object for the POST request
  $request2 = new httprequest;

  // Set request method and URL      
  $request2->setRequestMethod('POST');
  if (!$request2->setRequestURL($lastLocation = $url2)) exit("Error setting request URL: ".$request2->getLastErrorStr()."<br>\r\n");

  // All the other headers will be built by the class but we need
  // set this one explicitly
  $request2->setRequestHeader('Referer',$url1);

  // Get the cookies sent by the last request and forward them on
  $cookiejar = process_cookies($request1);
  if (count($cookiejar)) $request2->setRequestCookies($cookiejar);

  // Set the request body
  $data = array(
    'email'=>'testemail',
    'pass'=>'testpass'
  );
  $request2->setRequestControls($data);

  // We need to handle redirects ourselves to make sure the cookies are sent correctly
  $request2->setHandleRedirects(FALSE);

  // Keep looping until we get a 2xx response
  while (TRUE) {
    if (!$request2->sendRequest()) exit("Error sending request: ".$request2->getLastErrorStr()."<br>\r\n");
    if ($request2->getResponseCode() >= 200 && $request2->getResponseCode() < 300) break;
    if ($request2->getResponseCode() >= 300 && $request2->getResponseCode() < 400) {
      $nextLocation = $request2->getRequestHeader('location');
      if (!$nextLocation) exit("Error: Server responded with redirect response code ".$request2->getResponseCode().", but did not send a valid location header<br>\r\n");
      $cookiejar = process_cookies($request2,$cookiejar);
      $request2->resetRequestCookies();
      $request2->setRequestCookies($cookiejar);
      $request2->setRequestHeader('Referer',$lastLocation);
      if (!$request2->setRequestURL($lastLocation = $nextLocation)) exit("Error setting request URL: ".$request2->getLastErrorStr()."<br>\r\n");
      continue;
    }
    exit("Server responded with unhandled HTTP response code: ".$request2->getResponseCode()."<br>\r\n");
  }

  // validate and display the response
  if (!$response = $request2->getResponseBodyData(TRUE)) exit('Error: No body data returned<br>'."\r\n");
  exit($response);

?>
```

Comment: Sorry, fixed broken link... :S

Comment: You either get a header redirect that contains cookies that need to be sent back, or it is expecting cookies to be sent that should have been received by visiting facebook.com (the referrer). Try the edited code above.

Comment: Fix is: replace the line `$nextLocation = $request2->getRequestHeader('location');` with `$nextLocation = $request2->getResponseHeader('location');`. However, I have just been trying this with my FB account and it seems to get stuck in a redirect loop, where every response is 302, and it redirects to the same location over and over. I will keep playing with it and let you know if I get anywhere...

Comment: Not as yet, but to be honest I have been pretty busy at work over the last couple of days and haven't played with it much. I will probably have a chance to play with this tonight - I will let you know if I come up with a solution. What exactly are you trying to do - i.e. why do you want to do this auto-login, and what do you hope to achieve by it? There may be a better way, is all I'm thinking...

Comment: Thanks, take your time :) If I can contact you in an other way, I could tell you more about my project. Its a bit stupid with the login script, but I dont have another solution, so I need to have handled it like this... ICQ or something similar?